# HTML and CSS footer

Tags: html, css

Hello I have a problem regarding the footer part of this web page like for some reason the footer doesnt line up properly and im not sure whats wrong with it 
this is what its supposed to look like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKSrK.jpg) but this is what it looks like (https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1Acv.jpg). Just please tell me what i did wrong and that will be appreiated please and thank you.Also I have 0 errors on validator too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="cyclestyle.css">
          <title>Cycling Tours</title>
       </head>
       <body>
            <div id="container">
               <section id="header">
                      <header>
                         <nav>
                            <ul>
                               <li><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Ask Us">Ask Us</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Destination">Destination</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Seminars">Reviews</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Trip Prep">Trip Prep</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </nav>
                         <h1>Cycling Tours</h1>
                         <figure>
                            <img id="banner" src="images/cycling_banner.png" alt="cycling">
                         </figure>
                      </header>
                </section>  
                  <section id="aboutus">
                     <h3> About Us </h3>
                     <p> Cycling Tours began when Bill Randolf and three of his friends from high school began to cycle regularly every weekend. Their routine cycling evolved into frequent cycling trips and they cultivated a following. Before they knew it, other friends and family members asked to join them in their trips.</p>
                     <img src = "images/cyclists.jpeg" alt="cyclists"  class = "floatright">
                     <p>Cyclists are enthusiastic and very health and environmentally conscious. For this reason, all of our trips include vegan options for meals, recycled paper food serving utensils, and hybrid vehicles to escort the cyclists.</p>
                     <p>Our trips are suitable for solo cyclists, couples, friends, and families. We provide camping accommodation for off-road cycling trips, and shared accommodations for couples, friends and families. If you are travelling solo, we can match you with someone for shared accommodations. You can also pay the single-supplement if you wish to have a room of your own.</p>
                     <p>After you've completed one trip with us, we're sure you'll want to do more. Over 80% of our customers have been on at least one prior trip with us. We're always looking for new ideas for trips, so please let us know if you have any ideas!</p>
                  </section>
                  <section id="tripinfo">
                     <h3>Trip Information</h3>
                     <br>
                     <p>Our trips are planned carefully to provide the best experience for cyclists.</p>
                     <br>
                     <p>Types of trips include self-contained camping tours, inn-to-inn tours and other adventure cycling.</p>
                  </section>
                  <footer>
                      <div id = "footer">
                         <hr>
                         <hr>
                         <p>Cycling Tours&#10043 P.O. Box 4455&#10043 Brantford,ON&#10043 N3T 2J0 <br> Image Credit: http://www.bikelink.com/images/banner01.jpg </p>
                      </div>
                  </footer>
            </div>
        </body>

    </html>
```

cyclestyle.css

```
        * { 
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        }

        body {
            height:90vh;
        }

        p {
            text-indent: 50px; 
            line-height:1.5em;
        }

        #tripinfo {
            background-color:#bbccdd;
            float:right;
            width:20%;
            height:68.5vh;
        }

        header {


        }       

        #banner {
            width:100%;

        }

        nav {
        list-style-type: none;
        text-align: center;  
        text-decoration: none;  
        }

        nav li {
        display: inline ;

        }




        #container {
            width: 1000px;
            margin: 20px auto;
        }

        * {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        nav a{
            border: 2px solid black;
            padding: 8px;
            border-radius:10px 10px 0px 10px;
            text-decoration:none;
            background-color:#bbccdd;
            color:white;
            font-family: verdana;
            font-weight:bold;
        }
        a:hover {
            color: black;
        }


        #aboutus {
            float:left;
            width:80%;
            height:80vh;
        }
        h1 {
            position:absolute;
            font-family:Verdana;
            color:White;
            font-size:3.5em;
        }
        h3 {
            font-family:Verdana;
        }

        p {
            font-family:Verdana;
            font-size:.90em;
        }   

        #footer {
            text-align:centre;
            font-weight:bold;

        }

        #container {
            width: 1000px;

        }
```

Comment: You are not using the semantic tags correctly. When you have an element called <footer>, you don't need to place a <div id="footer"> inside of it, just add styles for the <footer>

Comment: I have tried that because I tried adding a border-top  to footer but for some reason the line goes under the header

Comment: banner i mean, the wide picture of with the white cycling text on it. I just tried the div id to see if it would make a difference

Comment: If you don't mind, I see some other problems way before I get to the footer: firstly, why is your <h1> position: absolute? You don't give it a location either top, left, etc. What are you trying to achieve there?

Comment: @stampgod did my answer helps you?

Comment: @Fiido93 Yes it did thank you very much now i got a proper border and the footer works properly I appreciate it. And I gave you an upvote but my reputation is still too low

Comment: @stampgod Please mark it as correct answer. On the left side if its help you. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Need to remember when you use the float. Always create another div that use CSS `clear:both` and it will push the next div to the bottom.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="cyclestyle.css">
          <title>Cycling Tours</title>
       </head>
       <body>
            <div id="container">
               <section id="header">
                      <header>
                         <nav>
                            <ul>
                               <li><a href="aboutus.html">About us</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Ask Us">Ask Us</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Destination">Destination</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="FAQ">FAQ</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Reviews">Reviews</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Seminars">Reviews</a></li>
                               <li><a href="a" title="Trip Prep">Trip Prep</a></li>
                            </ul>
                         </nav>
                         <h1>Cycling Tours</h1>
                         <figure>
                            <img id="banner" src="images/cycling_banner.png" alt="cycling">
                         </figure>
                      </header>
                </section>  
                  <section id="aboutus">
                     <h3> About Us </h3>
                     <p> Cycling Tours began when Bill Randolf and three of his friends from high school began to cycle regularly every weekend. Their routine cycling evolved into frequent cycling trips and they cultivated a following. Before they knew it, other friends and family members asked to join them in their trips.</p>
                     <img src = "images/cyclists.jpeg" alt="cyclists"  class = "floatright">
                     <p>Cyclists are enthusiastic and very health and environmentally conscious. For this reason, all of our trips include vegan options for meals, recycled paper food serving utensils, and hybrid vehicles to escort the cyclists.</p>
                     <p>Our trips are suitable for solo cyclists, couples, friends, and families. We provide camping accommodation for off-road cycling trips, and shared accommodations for couples, friends and families. If you are travelling solo, we can match you with someone for shared accommodations. You can also pay the single-supplement if you wish to have a room of your own.</p>
                     <p>After you've completed one trip with us, we're sure you'll want to do more. Over 80% of our customers have been on at least one prior trip with us. We're always looking for new ideas for trips, so please let us know if you have any ideas!</p>
                  </section>
                  <section id="tripinfo">
                     <h3>Trip Information</h3>
                     <br>
                     <p>Our trips are planned carefully to provide the best experience for cyclists.</p>
                     <br>
                     <p>Types of trips include self-contained camping tours, inn-to-inn tours and other adventure cycling.</p>
                  </section>
                  <div class="clearfix"></div>
                  <footer>
                      <div id = "footer">
                         <hr>
                         <hr>
                         <p>Cycling Tours&#10043 P.O. Box 4455&#10043 Brantford,ON&#10043 N3T 2J0 <br> Image Credit: http://www.bikelink.com/images/banner01.jpg </p>
                      </div>
                  </footer>
            </div>
        </body>

    </html>
```

**CSS**

```
* { 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    }

    body {
        height:90vh;
    }

    p {
        text-indent: 50px; 
        line-height:1.5em;
    }

    #tripinfo {
        background-color:#bbccdd;
        float:right;
        width:20%;
        height:68.5vh;
    }

    header {


    }       

    #banner {
        width:100%;

    }

    nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: center;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    }

    nav li {
    display: inline ;

    }




    #container {
        width: 1000px;
        margin: 20px auto;
    }

    * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    nav a{
        border: 2px solid black;
        padding: 8px;
        border-radius:10px 10px 0px 10px;
        text-decoration:none;
        background-color:#bbccdd;
        color:white;
        font-family: verdana;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
    a:hover {
        color: black;
    }


    #aboutus {
        float:left;
        width:80%;
        /* height:80vh; */ /* I remove this line */
    }
    h1 {
        position:absolute;
        font-family:Verdana;
        color:White;
        font-size:3.5em;
    }
    h3 {
        font-family:Verdana;
    }

    p {
        font-family:Verdana;
        font-size:.90em;
    }   

    .clearfix {
      clear:both;
    }

    #footer {
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;

    }

    #footer p {
      padding-top:10px;
    }

    #container {
        width: 1000px;

    }
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/p5ntcwr4/)

Answer (score 0):

To fix the margin you could try adding `float:right;width:100%;` into #footer and adding:

```
#footer p {
    padding-top:10px;
    padding-left:20%;
}
```

to fix the whacky text format.

`#footer and #footer p`:

```
    #footer {
        text-align:centre;
        font-weight:bold;
        float:right;
        width:100%;
    }
    #footer p {
        padding-top:10px;
        padding-left:20%;
    }
```

If you want to add some thickness into your hr line you could also add:

```
    hr {
        border: none;
        height: 1px;
        /* Set the hr color */
        color: #333; /* old IE */
        background-color: #333; /* Modern Browsers */
    }
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: thank you I just have a problem with the margins on the side because its too big like I would want a 10% fluid margin on the sides and ive tried doing margin-left and margin-right 10% on #container and it still didnt work